# Remove all instances from string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

```
[startstring]hello = guys[endstring] hello guys [startstring]jerk = you[endstring] man this is good!!!
```

I would like remove everything in between `[startstring]` and `[endstring]`, all the matches, and also remove the `[startstring]` and `[endstring]` from the string. So like the result would be:

```
hello guys  man this is good!!!
```

and the deleted stuff would be:

**[startstring]hello = guys[endstring]** hello guys **[startstring]jerk = you[endstring]** man this is good!!!

See what I mean?

I would like to echo the resulted stuff, without the `[startstring]` and `[endstring]` stuff, as shown above. :)

Hope I'm mostly clear. :-)

How would I go about accomplishing this in PHP? Would this envolve some sort of `RegEx`? Could you provide a sample code?

Thanks so much in advance! :-)

**Edit:** Could this code be modified or be used somewhat to complete the task?

```
preg_match_all('/\[startstring\](.*?)\[endstring\]/s', $input, $matches);
```

Comment: have you tried at least the `for` approach?

Comment: Just wondering what you've tried already?

Comment: Uh, this looks suspiciously like XML. Are you trying to parse items that are between XML tags or tags of some kind? IE <beginning>sorta stuff</end>, if so use an XML parser.

Comment: @FinalForm nope, this is not XML. I use SimpleXML for that stuff, which is much easier.

Comment: @hafichuk Added a snippet of code.

Comment: just use `preg_replace` instead `preg_match_all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that you just need to change your method name, you should use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $subject)
```

Searches subject for matches to pattern and replaces them with replacement.

#### Code

```
$input = "[startstring]hello = guys[endstring] hello guys [startstring]jerk = you[endstring] man this is good!!!";
$output = preg_replace('/\[startstring\](.*?)\[endstring\]/s', '', $input);
```

#### Output

> hello guys  man this is good!!!

Comment: her string probably doesn't have `[startstring]` and `[endstring]` literally so if there are no `[` or `]` chars then those are not needed

Comment: I maybe know what are you trying to say, and yes, it can be configurable

Comment: @TheOptometrist I do have `[startstring]` and `[endstring]` in my string. Sorry for the confusion.